# How to remove HTTPS to HTTP Security Alert message in .Net

Tags: asp.net

How to disable or block that Security Alert so that when any user access my Secured Page he 
will not get Security Alert Dialog. Any help will be appreciated and thank 
you in advance.

Thanks
Narendra Singh

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the security of a page is recognized at the browser level, and it is the browser that raises the security alert. Is it true that you are doing a redirect in your .NET code from an https page to an http page? If so, the cause is that the browser has detected a transfer from a secure page to an unsecured page without the user's consent, which causes a warning.

I'm unsure of your situation, but one way to get around this is to have the user click an html link that goes to an http page. The reason this will work, is that the browser recognizes this as the user's choice, and not a behind the scenes redirect.